# If $S = \sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k})}$ , find $10S$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, problem-solving

If
$$
 S = \sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1})(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k})} ,
$$
find $10S.$

**What I tried** : Multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator I get:
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\sqrt{k(k+1)}(\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k})}{k(k+1)}.
$$

From here I thought this would be a telescopic sum and a partial fraction decomposition would take place. But unfortunately I didn't find any. This was my only thoughts on this problem so far.

Can anyone help?

Wolfram Alpha is giving the answer to be $S = 1.1$ , but how is it coming?

Comment: Did you try taking the k(k+1) part in the denominator, inside the root??

Comment: You mean multiplying both it by $\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)}$ ?

Comment: Using desmos it gives me 10S = 7.05390762599, so maybe its an irrational value

Comment: It maybe some irrational value , but what's the method?

Comment: @Anonymous Can you please validate the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem is in fact
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\frac 1{\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k} }$$ which now simplifies a lot since
$$S= \sum_{k=1}^{99}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)$$ And $10\,S$ is a whole number.

**Edit**

If we consider
$$T_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+3}{2}\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\right)$$ is *seems* that, for $1\leq n \leq 2^{30}$, there are only three values of $n$ such that $10\, S_n$ is a whole number (namely $3$, $24$ and $99$).

Comment: But the OP had a square root on top of it

Comment: @MathLover. I know that but I am sure (say at a level of $99.9999999$% that there is a typo. Cheers :-)

Comment: I think you are right. I was wondering too.

Comment: Sadly , there is no typo .

Comment: @Anonymous. Do you want to bet ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Anonymous do you have the answer key, if so we can validate

Comment: The answer is not known to me , wait a minute . There is a small typo I have made !!

Comment: @Anonymous. If I am right, you give me a cent. If you are right, I take you for a very nice lunch in a very good French restaurant. Is is OK ? Ping me here when you have the answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't want to bet , I am wrong . There was a small typo regarding the square root sign . By the way, I am not giving you a cent . :) (Also I don't live in France) .

Comment: @Anonymous. OK ... but I won ! Cheers and good luck in your studies. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please let me know if I miss something in the discussion, but I'm wondering why nobody calculated the sum explicitly yet: $$S= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\right) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}+1$$ after an index shift in the second sum $k+1\rightarrow k$.

Comment: Yeah that was it . I already found it when I spotted the small typo I made.